# check user password in mybb

Tags: php, passwords, mybb

I use this script to check mybb password but I get this error: " NO ".
I used mybb password encryption method but I don't know why this isn't working?

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
$MySQL_Host = "localhost";
$MySQL_User = "root";
$MySQL_Pass = "";
$MySQL_DB = "mybb";

$username = 'me';
$password = 'you';

mysql_connect("$MySQL_Host", "$MySQL_User", "$MySQL_Pass") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
mysql_select_db("$MySQL_DB") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT uid, password, email FROM mybb_users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".md5(md5($salt).md5($password))."';");
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

if( md5(md5($salt).md5($password)) == $result[ 0 ][ 'password' ] )
        {
        echo "yes" ;

//i need this option
        return array( 'id' => $result[ 0 ][ 'uid' ],
                          'mail' => $result[ 0 ][ 'email' ],
                          'user' => $username
                        );
         }
else
echo "no";


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$result[ 0 ][ 'password' ]` is empty because you forgot to fetch:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT uid, password, email FROM mybb_users WHERE username='".$username."' AND password='".md5(md5($salt).md5($password))."';");
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

And now just check if record exists:

```
if( $row !== false )
{
    echo "yes" ;

    //i need this option
    return array( 
        'id' => $row[ 'uid' ],
        'mail' => $row[ 'email' ],
        'user' => $username
    );
} else
    echo "no";
```

Comment: not worked also have same error : NO  i think its have problem about mybb password encription

Answer (score 0):

From where did you get the `$salt`?
You need to fetch the salt from DB as well (there are separate salt saved per user) and encrypt user entered password with that salt to compare password of DB.